# My windows 7 now has touch-screen mode on, how do I disable it?

Tags: windows-7, touchscreen

So, I have a fairly new EliteBook 8570p, but when I was working a sign came on and showed a finger wiping across a screen. I soon realized that turned on touchscreen even though I don't have a touchscreen for my Windows 7. I have tried doing "Touch and Pen" and that doesn't work. When I looked on here I saw a post somewhat like this and the answer said to look on the "Device Manager", but when I looked there was still nothing there. How do I fix this it really bothers me.

Comment: Never mind I ended up finding it when I looked at Synaptic pointing device. :D

Comment: Could you please describe your solution as an answer and accept your own answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this:

Use the command

```
dism /online /disable-feature:TabletPCOC
```

or through the sequence:
Start > Control Panel > Programs and Features > Turn Windows Features On or Off > UNcheck the box for "Tablet PC Components" and OK etc.